# Non Exempt salary over time

Tags: united-states, overtime

I was just recently switched from Exempt to Nonexempt and I work 40 hours a week.  Can an employer enforce not paying for overtime unless its"preapproved by the company first" before they have to pay time and a half according to the law?

Comment: What is your location of employment?

Comment: @PeterM - by referring to "Exempt" and "Non-Exempt", the location can't really be anywhere else than the USA.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand the question.  If you work 40 hours a week, you wouldn't get overtime.  A policy that overtime has to be pre-approved is pretty common.  If the company doesn't want to pay overtime, doesn't authorize overtime, and doesn't have you work overtime, then they don't have to pay overtime.

Comment: @JustinCave I think the OP is saying that they *normally* work 40 hours a week, as opposed to being part-time.

Comment: @brhans There may be state laws in play as well.  Plus not everyone on here is from the US and would know that.

Comment: Minnesota, Definition of non-exempt employee
Most employees are entitled to overtime pay under the Fair Labor Standards Act. They are called non-exempt employees. Employers must pay them one-and-a-half times their regular rate of pay when they work more than 40 hours in a week.

Comment: Now being non-exempt employee I have to punch in and out each day so the time clock is keeping track of my 40 hours worked and anything over and above that, but what I am wondering is can a employer deny paying any over time based on the stipulation that they put in writing that they are requiring a preapproval by the company before overtime is paid out and having the employee "sign off" on this understanding?    Will the FLSA law accept this reasoning by an employer in not having to pay an employee overtime based off the company stating it in writng that it has to be preapproved FIRST?

Comment: I'm in transportation and having to jump on line after hours if need be is not uncommon for me to do to keep things moving.

Comment: If you work overtime, you have to be paid for that overtime.  If you work overtime without authorization, your employer is free to terminate you.

Comment: Stop trying to close this. It's not company-specific and it's legal INFORMATION (as opposed to advice) that any HR professional could address.

Answer (score 5):

In the US, if you are non-exempt, generally overtime must be paid at time-and-a-half for anything over 40 hours.  It's illegal to not pay you at the correct rate.

But then again, it's not illegal to not *offer* overtime.

Read up on the [Fair Labor Standard Act](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/f/fair-labor-standards-act-flsa.asp).

Comment: So if they require pre-approval for overtime, you can refuse to work any overtime until it has been approved, in writing.

Comment: @DavidK That doesn't make any sense.  If OP's manager is asking or requiring OP to work overtime, the law doesn't make any distinction about needing a written approval.  If the manager requests that employee work the overtime, then the company is on the hook to pay it, no matter what.

Comment: I can tell you that legally my sister had to pay her employees overtime if they worked it whether it was approved or not because of a state labor law. However, working unapproved overtime can be grounds to fire you which is what she did to the employee after she had been repeatedly told not to work overtime. So you might get the extra money once or twice, but it is not worth it.

Comment: Fair point. I can just see possibility of disputes over precisely when and how much overtime was requested by the employer, especially if there was only a verbal conversation. It's always better to get things in writing.

Comment: @HLGEM on that point, you're correct.  I know someone who worked for Wal-mart.  Clocking ONE minute of distinctly unapproved overtime there is grounds for a write-up ("counseling").

Comment: @codenoir, I had a former colleague who used to work an hourly, non-exempt position for the Navy. He would stop in mid sentence at quitting time because of that same sort of thing. Even though he was no longer hourly or non-exempt, 20 years of doing that were a hard habit to break.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that overtime had to be paid absolutely no matter what, even if the employer did not request it.

Comment: @DavidK I think it has to be set up that way because otherwise there could be hints that employees need to stay late without pay.

Comment: @DavidK: If you have an employee that regularly does "known, but unauthorized" overtime and you don't pay them, the goverment is going to interpret that as "required unpaid overtime" if they find out about it. So, unless the employee is exempt, they will require the company to pay the overtime, pay for the investigation, and pay fines.  Which is why people can get fired for working unauthorized overtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your company has a policy that any time worked beyond 40 hours must be approved.  So if you do work beyond 40 hours with out approval then you are violating that policy.  If a supervisor orders you to work overtime with out management approval then they are violating that policy.

Either way your employer is required to follow the law regarding compensation.  If you work 41 hours in a week they are required to pay that 1 hour at time and a half regardless of if it was approved or not.

However, If you worked that extra hour with out approval then you could be subject to disciplinary action.  This is no different that if you are scheduled to work 8-5 and you decide on your own to come back it at 8pm after everyone has left and work another 4 hours.  They must pay you for that time you worked, even though it was not authorized or approved.  But they are probably going to some sort of disciplinary action.  And it is conceivable that working unapproved and unauthorized hours could result in your termination for cause.